# Magento - link to a frontend skin js file from an admin file

Tags: magento

I'm already using jQuery in my frontend skin files. I've now added some extra functionality in an admin phtml file, that also needs to use jQuery. I don't want to have to include it twice, but how can I link to the existing jQuery file dynamically, assuming I don't know what theme package name is being used on the frontend (because obviously that can change, so I don't want it hardcoded)?

For example, I tried this, but it gives me the admin theme package name, not the frontend package:

```
<?php
    // Get the package name
    $configData = Mage::getStoreConfig('design');
    $package = $configData['package']['name'];
?>
```

Anyone?

Comment: Why did you put javascript in `/skin` and not in `/js`?

Comment: Because it's theme specific, so it's in skin/frontend/themename/js

Comment: Since jQuery is a library I wouldn't resist putting it in the generic `/js` folder. Otherwise I would put it in each theme that I thought needed it, it is only 50KB after all. I've worked on sites with nearly 50GB of pictures! A bit of javascript doesn't seem so bad in comparison. Or you could include it directly from code.google.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this seems to be working. I can access the db directly, look for the "design/package/name" in the core_config_data table and then build the url to the js file using that:

```
<?php // Get the current theme being used, so we can build the url link to our jQuery file
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$tablename = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('core_config_data');
$results = $connection->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM $tablename WHERE path='design/package/name';");
foreach($results as $row) { $theme = $row['value']; };
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN).'frontend/'.$theme; ?>/default/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you must go this route please don't query the database directly, there are many things that can change unexpectedly and it is inefficient. Instead use `$theme = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/package/name', $storeId)` where `$storeId` is of a known store. Magento is probably already caching the entire config which saves a lot of effort for you.

Comment: That's what I tried first, but as I said, it always returns the admin package name, which is default, as opposed to the frontend skin package name.

Answer (score 0):

for me helped to set $storeId as 1 not 0

```
$package = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/package/name', 1);
$theme   = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/default', 1);
```